# Create cone geometry with flat base in three.js?

Tags: three.js

Trying to figure out how to create something that looks like the image below... Tried searching around but couldn't really figure it out...

[image: Tapered Cone Sample]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with `CylinderGeometry`. This class allows to define different radii for the top and bottom.

```js
let mesh;
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.2, 0.5, 1, 16);
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setAnimationLoop(animation);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animation(time) {

  mesh.rotation.x = time / 2000;
  mesh.rotation.y = time / 1000;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.133.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
```